# Merging Excel sheets by categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to attach categories from a different dataset to another dataset using Excel if that makes any sense. For example, I am given a dataset:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Happy |
| 1 | Sad |
| 2 | Angry |

And dataset:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | today |
| Bob | 1 | tomorrow |
| Ron | 2 | yesterday |
| Sally | 1 | yesterday |
| Amy | 2 | today |
| Lin | 0 | yesterday |

I want the data to end up looking like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | today | Happy |
| Bob | 1 | tomorrow | Sad |
| Ron | 2 | yesterday | Angry |
| Sally | 1 | yesterday | Sad |
| Amy | 2 | today | Angry |
| Lin | 0 | yesterday | Happy |

I was told to use a VLookUp formula to make it happen, but every single time that I try, I get NA values, and I have no idea how to approach the problem. I am also somewhat new to Excel.

Comment: What is the VLOOKUP you tried, because that is the answer.

Comment: it was specifically, using this case, =VLOOKUP(B2, sheet1!A1:B4, 2)

Answer (score 0):

`=VLOOKUP(B2, sheet1!$A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE)` drop it in D2 and drag down. Without $ it moves range you are looking at when dragging

Or you can lookup for whole array:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2:B7, sheet1!$A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE)
```